# How do avoid read-only transaction error when reading an entity and then save an entity using Spring Data repositories in a @RestController?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

In a Spring `@RestController` method I am trying to first check if an entity exists before saving it using Spring Data CrudRepository so that I can return a 404 Not Found response when calling a PUT to a sub-resource that doesn't exist. If the entity exists it will then try and save calling `myObjectDao.save(myObject)` but I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries
>   leading to data modification are not allowed  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2108)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2578)

Here is my repository and controller:

```
public interface MyObjectDao extends CrudRepository<MyObject, Integer> {
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("my-object")
public class MyObjectRestController {

    @Autowired
    private MyObjectDao myObjectDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public MyObject update(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id,
            @RequestBody @Valid MyObject myObject) {

        if (!myObjectDao.exists(id)) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(String.format("Entity with id %s cannot be found.", id));
        }
        MyObject.setId(id);
        return myObjectDao.save(myObject);
    }
```

It seems as though Spring is marking the transaction as read-only once `myObjectDao.exists(id)` is called and reusing that transaction for the save. How can I check if an entity exists and then save it without getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: Need your dao code to have a better insight.

Comment: My dao code is there. It's using Spring Data and is the interface MyObjectDao, which Spring provides the implementation under the hood.

Comment: I am using org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter but I don't think that should have anything to do with it.

Comment: If you do not have a transaction configuration setup, then OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter would probably be the reason for this. It binds JPA Entity Manager in a read-only execution mode if no transactional configuration is setup. From javadoc: It is suitable for service layer transactions via TransactionManager or JtaTransactionManager as well as **for non-transactional read-only execution**.

Comment: I have this defined as the transaction manager:
<bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>

Comment: You mentioned in one of you comments on an answer that you tried adding `@Transactional` annotation. Does your configuration have something like this along with that: `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

Comment: Yes I have `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />`

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `@Transactional` directly to the *update* method to declare a non read-only transaction that will be propagated to `exists` and `save` (assuming you're using declarative transaction management)?

Comment: I've tried it there and on the repository interface and even at the top of the controller as read-only false, also redeployed and nothing affects it!

Comment: @dukethrash might be a dead end but what mysql connector version are you using? https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38747

Comment: I'm using mysql-connector-java 5.1.33 which the link you provided says the bug was fixed in 5.1.7.